# Почему нет метода getResourceId для ImageView? (Android)

Tags: java, android, imageview

Подскажите, почему у класса `ImageView` есть атрибут

```
private int mResource = 0;
```

В котором хранится Id ресурса :

```
public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
   ...
   mResource = resId;
   ...
}
```

Но нет никакого метода чтобы его получить? И вместо этого необходимо извращаться добавляя тэги при инициализации, и узнавать идентификатор изображения по ним.

Comment: рефлексия всегда поможет)

Comment: Потому что его не реализовали разработчики из Google. Ваш кэп. А вообще если вам понадобился такой метод то имхо вы делаете что то не так.

Answer (score 1):

Спрашивать об этом надо у гугла, но, думаю, не ошибусь, предположив что это из-за того, что не только из ресурсов можно назначить картинку для `ImageView` и им проще было запретить спрашивать об этом, чем делать кучу проверок и возвращать `null`/`-1` из подобного метода.

И да, если вам понадобился такой метод значит вы что-то не так делаете. Скорее всего вам надо просто завести некий массив, куда и сложить `ID` ваших картинок.

Comment: Спасибо.  Про то что его нет потому как не реализовали конечно же понятно.  Если это запрещено, значит есть большая вероятность что придёт null/-1, а из-за чего она большая? Всё таки она инициируется конкретным методом.  И можете пояснить почему если метод требуется то я делаю что-то не так? Мне например он нужен для определения типа картинки в RecyclerView.Adapter. Мне не нужно знать какому item соответствует конкретный ImageView, для меня кажется логичным что я просто узнаю в свойствах id ресурса и поступаю соответствующе.

Comment: @SergeyChalbyshev, ну, просто все уже привыкли к тому, что из View не вытащить идентификатор ресурса, можно вытащить только отображаемые данные, вот и считается, что вы делаете что-то не так. Т.е. данные у вас отображаемые должны быть отдельно и именно с ними вы должны оперировать и не включать в логику участие View.